# why chgrp or chown command causes file loss xattr

Tags: linux, c, chown, chgrp

```
[root@localhost ~]# getfattr -m - -d /bin/tcpm
getfattr: Removing leading '/' from absolute path names
# file: bin/tcpm
security.capability=0sAQAAAgAUAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA=
security.selinux="system_u:object_r:bin_t:s0"

[root@localhost ~]# chgrp 951 /bin/tcpm
[root@localhost ~]# getfattr -m - -d /bin/tcpm
getfattr: Removing leading '/' from absolute path names
# file: bin/tcpm
security.selinux="system_u:object_r:bin_t:s0"
```

after `chown` `uid` `/bin/tcpm` or `chgrp`  `gid` `/bin/tcpm`，`/bin/tcpm` loss xattr(security.capability)

#`/bin/tcpm` provides by `tcpm-kmod`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[The `coreutils.info` documentation on `chown`](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/chown-invocation.html) says:

> The ‘chown’ command sometimes clears the set-user-ID or set-group-ID
> permission bits.  This behavior depends on the policy and functionality
> of the underlying ‘chown’ system call, which may make system-dependent
> file mode modifications outside the control of the ‘chown’ command.  For
> example, the ‘chown’ command might not affect those bits when invoked by
> a user with appropriate privileges, or when the bits signify some
> function other than executable permission (e.g., mandatory locking).
> When in doubt, check the underlying system behavior.

So it's time to look at the `chown()` system call (i.e. [`man 2 chown`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/chown.2.html)):

> When the owner or group of an executable file is changed by an unprivileged user, the S_ISUID and S_ISGID mode bits are cleared. POSIX does not specify whether this also should happen when root does the `chown()`; the Linux behavior depends on the kernel version, and since Linux 2.2.13, root is treated like other users.  In case of a non-group-executable file (i.e., one for which the S_IXGRP bit is not set) the S_ISGID bit indicates mandatory locking, and is not cleared by a chown().
>
> When the owner or group of an executable file is changed (by any user), all capability sets for the file are cleared.

In other words: whenever the owner or group of an executable file is changed, the system will automatically remove any special privileges from the file. This includes not only the SUID/SGID bits, but also capabilities.

The removal of special privileges is not done by the `chown` or `chgrp` command, but by the system call those commands use to do their job, so any other way to change the group or owner of a file should also cause its special privileges to be removed.

The reason for removal of special privileges is not stated, but I would guess it blocks a class of attacks that would allow an user to gain extra privileges by manipulating another user and/or a root-owned process to change the group or owner of a privileged program.